# I can't get the speed of the user, have tried many methods

Tags: android, location

I've been currently trying to get the speed of the user.

I've got the location and time of the two points, but it seems that I just kind find the correct way to calculate the speed, despite many attempts.

This is what I am trying right now:

```
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Location Changed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if (settings == null) {
        settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    }

    int ExceedingLimit = settings.getInt("ExceedLimit", 10);
    int LowerLimit = settings.getInt("LowerLimit", 2);
    int UpperLimit = settings.getInt("UpperLimit", 12);

    double speed = 0;
    if (location != null) {
        double calc_long = Math.pow(location.getLongitude() - OldLocation.getLongitude(), 2);
        double calc_lat = Math.pow(location.getLatitude() - OldLocation.getLatitude(), 2);
        double time = (double) location.getTime() - (double) OldLocation.getTime();
        speed = Math.sqrt(calc_long + calc_lat) / time;
    }
    if (location != null && location.hasSpeed()) {
        speed = location.getSpeed();
    }

    if (LowerLimit < speed && speed < UpperLimit) {
        ExceedInstance += 1;
    }

    OldLocation = location;
```

It doesn't seem to work, as it stays on zero even when moving.

I initialise Old Location here:

```
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "You have connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result =
            LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(mLocationClient, mLocationSettingsRequest
            );
    result.setResultCallback(ViewingWindow.this);

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        OldLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mLocationClient);
    }
}
```

I've also attempted calculate the two separately and dividing the two, but it ended up as a casting error and it still stayed on zero.

Casting doesn't work either. When I cast it to double, it gives me E-10 to E-11 numbers, absurdly low but still changing every time the location updates.

The problem is, even when I move the speed doesn't go but.

I actually have no idea why any of this is wrong. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to cast the needed time to double ?

```
speed = (double)Math.sqrt(
            Math.pow(location.getLongitude() - OldLocation.getLongitude(), 2)
                    + Math.pow(location.getLatitude() - OldLocation.getLatitude(), 2)
    ) / (double)(location.getTime() - OldLocation.getTime());
```

Because i dont know what the Math.sqrt() returns. It may be returnes a float because it is much faster in caculation.

If your speed isnt to high you can also change the speed variable to float.

Comment: Now it's stuck on a specific value  3.5 m/s .

Comment: Okay, now it's on 0.5 m/s

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
double calc_long = Math.pow(location.getLongitude() - OldLocation.getLongitude(), 2);
double calc_lat = Math.pow(location.getLatitude() - OldLocation.getLatitude(), 2);
double time = location.getTime() - OldLocation.getTime();

speed = (double) Math.sqrt(calc_long + calc_lat) / time;
```

Also, how do you test the speed? From my experience longitude and latitude need a few seconds to update and register any move, so if you try to keep a constant speed for around a minute (doesn't matter how) it should trigger the speed meter.

Comment: I've got my fastestInterval set at 3 seconds, which I thought would be long enough to allow Long and Lat to update.

Comment: 3 seconds should be enough. Try to make every variable double like I showed in my answer and put break points on every line to see the value of every variable, cause it's possible to have null value of the variables sometimes even though I doubt that's the case here.

Comment: Huh, now it's showing absurdly small numbers, but even though when I move, it stays small, when it should become bigger. I guess that's the result of changing everything to double, though it doesn't exactly fix things. I'll try to make everything double.

Comment: ...it doesn't work. The numbers are small, and it doesn't seem to grow even after changing everything to double.

Comment: Is it possible that you're not calculating it right?

Comment: Where do you think I'm missing out?

Comment: Comment out the second if and put speed = location.getSpeed(); instead of double calc_long = Math.pow(location.getLongitude() - OldLocation.getLongitude(), 2);
        double calc_lat = Math.pow(location.getLatitude() - OldLocation.getLatitude(), 2);
        double time = (double) location.getTime() - (double) OldLocation.getTime();

Comment: so you mean replace the whole thing altogether with location.getSpeed()?

Comment: Alright, it's now stuck on 0.5m/s... it's progress, I guess?

Comment: Okay, I think the problem is in updating the OldLocation to NewLocation, since the location is consistently at 0.5 m/s, or some other value. Though for now, I can't see where.